# Select and output specific CSV file records

Tags: powershell, csv

This is the CSV data I have:

```
Host                            Description
devas1.devad.myworldpanel.com   check_check_cpu
devas1.devad.myworldpanel.com   check_interface_eth0
devetl1.devad.myworldpanel.com  check_check_cpu
devetl1.devad.myworldpanel.com  check_interface_eth0
devetl1.devad.myworldpanel.com  check_interface_eth1
devetl1.devad.myworldpanel.com  check_memory
devmart1.devad.myworldpanel.com mount-check_usr
devmart1.devad.myworldpanel.com mount-check_var
devnfs1.devad.myworldpanel.com  check_check_cpu
devnfs1.devad.myworldpanel.com  check_interface_eth0
devnfs1.devad.myworldpanel.com  check_memory
devnfs1.devad.myworldpanel.com  check_uptime
```

I have a GUI where I select the server names, and from there the respective records for those servers should be selected from the CSV and output to another CSV.

e.g.

If I select `devas1.devad.myworldpanel.com`, and `devnfs1.devad.myworldpanel.com`, then my new CSV should have:

```
Host                            Description
devas1.devad.myworldpanel.com   check_check_cpu
devas1.devad.myworldpanel.com   check_interface_eth0
devnfs1.devad.myworldpanel.com  check_check_cpu
devnfs1.devad.myworldpanel.com  check_interface_eth0
devnfs1.devad.myworldpanel.com  check_memory
devnfs1.devad.myworldpanel.com  check_uptime
```

I need some idea on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

We do not see any of the GUI, but assuming your CSV looks like this:

```
Host,Description
devas1.devad.myworldpanel.com,check_check_cpu
devas1.devad.myworldpanel.com,check_interface_eth0
devetl1.devad.myworldpanel.com,check_check_cpu
devetl1.devad.myworldpanel.com,check_interface_eth0
devetl1.devad.myworldpanel.com,check_interface_eth1
devetl1.devad.myworldpanel.com,check_memory
devmart1.devad.myworldpanel.com,mount-check_usr
devmart1.devad.myworldpanel.com,mount-check_var
devnfs1.devad.myworldpanel.com,check_check_cpu
devnfs1.devad.myworldpanel.com,check_interface_eth0
devnfs1.devad.myworldpanel.com,check_memory
devnfs1.devad.myworldpanel.com,check_uptime
```

and the selected items are in an array like

```
$selectedItems = 'devas1.devad.myworldpanel.com','devnfs1.devad.myworldpanel.com'
```

Then you could do this:

```
$csv = Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\allhosts.csv'
$selectedItems = 'devas1.devad.myworldpanel.com','devnfs1.devad.myworldpanel.com'

$csv | Where-Object { $_.Host -in $selectedItems } | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\SelectedData.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

to produce a new csv:

```
Host                           Description         
----                           -----------         
devas1.devad.myworldpanel.com  check_check_cpu     
devas1.devad.myworldpanel.com  check_interface_eth0
devnfs1.devad.myworldpanel.com check_check_cpu     
devnfs1.devad.myworldpanel.com check_interface_eth0
devnfs1.devad.myworldpanel.com check_memory        
devnfs1.devad.myworldpanel.com check_uptime
```